# Select all users that has a status of UN and their past status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that list users and addresses and the status EG

```
user Address       Status
1    2 water road  UN
1    3 black road  Ended
2    1 water road  Ended 
3    1 phill road  Ended
```

i have data like this but in the thousands.

i want to show all users that has a current status of UN and show their ended as well,
i dont want to see user that only has a ended status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    UserAddresses UA1
WHERE 
    EXISTS( SELECT * FROM 
                UserAddresses UA2 
            WHERE 
                UA1.user = UA2.user 
                and UA2.Status='UN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not seem to have any column which would indicate that any given status be *current*.  Assuming you want to find users who have both a `UN` and `Ended` status record, then aggregation is one option:

```
SELECT user
FROM yourTable
WHERE Status IN ('UN', 'Ended')
GROUP BY user
HAVING MIN(Status) <> MAX(Status);
```

Comment: But i dont want users that only have a ended status

Comment: @JD_123 My answer already checks for this.  Only users with _both_ statuses would be returned.

Comment: ok will give it a go, my brain is on fire with everything else in life and im having a brain fart on something simple

Comment: Well, I'm glad that I'm not sitting next to you right now :-)

Comment: so the IN shows both but when i do the having i get nothing back

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tablename t1
where not exists ( select 1 from tablename  t2 where t1.user=t2.user and t1.status='ended')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where status <> 'Ended' or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.user = t.user and t2.status <> 'Ended'
             );
```

This selects all "not ended" statuses and only the "ended" one for users that have another status.